# How to get base url form json in laravel 5.3?

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, laravel-5.3

My JavaScript code is like this:

```
$.getJSON("{{ url('/dropdowns/satkers') }}" + "/" + $("#kdkotama").val(), function(data) {
    ...
});
```

My blade view is like this :

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    {!! Form::label('kdkotama', 'Kotama:') !!}
    {!! Form::select('kdkotama', $tkotam, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'kdkotama']) !!}
</div>
```

I see in console, there is exist error like this:

[image: pic]

should have the correct URL like this:

http://localhost/mysystem/public/dropdowns/satkers/06

Is there any people who can help me?

Comment: Is your code inside a blade view?

Comment: Could you post the error here, rather than linking to it please.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a simple bug, but I can't test on live template.
Maybe you can try this:

```
$.getJSON("<?= url('/dropdowns/satkers') ?>" + "/" + $("#kdkotama").val(), function(data) {
    ...
});
```